# Postgresql Percentile_Cont not working: function percentile_cont(numeric, character varying, numeric) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, median

I have a table TableX looks like:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 100 |
| Cathy | 500 |
| Cathy | 200 |
| Cathy | 100 |

And I would like to process the **median** on column Value to obtain:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 100 |
| Cathy | 200 |

I'm trying to use the percentile_cont:

```
select name, percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by name, value) from TableX
```

But obtained error:

```
ERROR:  function percentile_cont(numeric, character varying, numeric) does not exist
```

My postgresql version is 13+, and that the following line actually works.

```
SELECT percentile_cont(array(SELECT j/10.0 FROM generate_series(1,10) j)) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY i) AS median FROM generate_series(1,11) AS s(i);
```

Pretty sure my script is wrong... would appreciate your thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table percent_test (name varchar, value float);

insert into percent_test values ('Bob', 100), ('Cathy', 500), ('Cathy', 200), ('Cathy', 100);

select name, percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by value) from  percent_test group  by name;
 name  | percentile_cont 
-------+-----------------
 Bob   |             100
 Cathy |             200
```

Per [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

> percentile_cont ( fraction double precision ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY double precision ) → double precision

> percentile_cont ( fraction double precision ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY interval ) → interval

> Computes the continuous percentile, a value corresponding to the specified fraction within the ordered set of aggregated argument values. This will interpolate between adjacent input items if needed.

So the `order by` in the `within group` can only be a numeric value not a character value. Push the `name` grouping out to the `from` part of the query.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer and the thorough explanations! It works like a charm :D